# how to give visitor permission for top site and member perm for Shared Documents

Tags: permissions

SharePoint 2013 Office 365

I have a group of users whom I want to be visitors/view only of the top parent level page and sub-level wiki pages too.

But I want these same users to have member/edit perms to the Shared Documents folder. I want them to be able to upload/delete/edit content here and here only.

How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must break / stop inheriting permission for the Shared Documents folder.

Go to SharePoint library -> Library tab -> Library settings.

Click on "Permissions for  this document library "

Click the Stop Inheriting Permissions button in the Permission Tools tab Edit group.

after that, you can specify special permission for that shared document folder.

Comment: Thanks Adhitya,

I tried that, but the user then gets edit perms everywhere.
I added a pic in my initial thread to help clarify what I'm looking to do.

Any thoughts?

Many Thanks,

Comment: have you make sure, to stop inheriting permission for that documents library ?